# Limit of the SQL statement

Tags: database, mysql

Is there a limit on the SQL query string you can pass to MySQL for it to execute?

Answer (score 2):

there is an limit of one **gigabyte** per Query.

[MySQL Query Limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html)

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, 1GB is the maximum size of the query. However, the limit might be lower depending on the hosting configurations.